# Sending messages over secure (SSL) WebSockets from Python to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, websocket

I have a C++ app, that embeds a Python script.
The C++ app sends `cv::Mat` images to the Py script, that in turn runs some image recognition (via a CNN). Basic idea can be found in [my gist](https://gist.github.com/Xonxt/26d2a9ac6c56505d0896822ede99a646).

Then my Python script wants to send the results of the CNN-prediction to another app (in Unity I believe) via secure WebSockets with SSL.

I don't have access to the actual Unity app at the moment, so I have to test the actual "sending" part using a simple Python server-app.

I don't have much experience (or knowledge) with sockets and SSL in Python, so I'm hoping for some help.

Everything works if I just use a non-secure HTTP connection, but when I try to introduce HTTPS and SSL, I get problems.

## SERVER SIDE:

In the last attempt, I was using the following server script (taken from [here](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#secure-example)):

```
import asyncio
import pathlib
import ssl
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"< {name}")

    ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain(
        pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name('cert.pem'), 
        pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name('key_wopasswd.pem'))

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 443, ssl=ssl_context)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

The certificate and key files were given to me by a colleague, who's in charge of the actual receiving Unity app.

## CLIENT SIDE:

After that I tried to connect and send messages either like this (**fragment 1**):

```
import json
import http.client, ssl
import time

ws = None
def send(msg="lol"):
    global ws
    if ws is None:
        ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
        ssl_context.load_cert_chain('cert.pem', 'key_wopasswd.pem')
        ws = http.client.HTTPSConnection("localhost", 443, context=ssl_context)
        ws.connect()
        print("connected successfully!")
    else:
        jsonString = json.dumps({"Time":int(time.time()), "Message":msg})
        ws.send(jsonString.encode('utf-8'))
```

In which case, simply nothing happens.

Or like this (**fragment 2**):

```
import websocket, ssl
import time

ws = None
def send(msg="lol"):
    global ws
    if ws is None: 
        ws = websocket.WebSocket(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                                         "ssl_version": ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, 
                                         "certfile": "cert.pem", 
                                         "keyfile": "key_wopasswd.pem"})
        ws.connect("wss://localhost:443")        
    else:
        jsonString = json.dumps({"Time":int(time.time()), "Message":msg})        
        ws.send(jsonString.encode('utf-8'))
```

In which case, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\client2.py", line 21, in send
    ws.connect("wss://localhost:443")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 220, in connect
    options.pop('socket', None))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\websocket\_http.py", line 126, in connect
    sock = _ssl_socket(sock, options.sslopt, hostname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\websocket\_http.py", line 253, in _ssl_socket
    sock = _wrap_sni_socket(sock, sslopt, hostname, check_hostname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\websocket\_http.py", line 232, in _wrap_sni_socket
    server_hostname=hostname,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
```

I also tried a simple `http.server.HTTPServer`, but the only difference was that with the first client (**Fragment 1**), it did not print the messages after every send, but instead accumulated all the received messages and printed all of them together after I stop the client, with the error: **code 400, message Bad request syntax**.

tl;dr
**Basically, what I need, is a good example of how I can connect to a secure HTTPS server with SSL once, and then continue sending string-messages, until the app stops.**

### A small update:

It works, if I write the client like this, but only if I close and reopen the connection after every message:

```
import json
import websocket, ssl
import time

ws = None
def send(msg="..."):
    global ws
    if ws is None:
        ws = websocket.WebSocket(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE,
                                         "ssl_version": ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, 
                                         "certfile": "cert.pem", 
                                         "keyfile": "key_wopasswd.pem"})
        ws.connect("wss://localhost:443")

    jsonString = json.dumps({"Time":int(time.time()), "Message":msg})
    ws.send(jsonString.encode('utf-8'))         
    ws.close()       
    ws = None 

########################
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i = i + 1
    send("i = %d" % i)
```